# Cannot visualize Sonnet module graph in Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have created a simple functional module using Sonnet:

```
class MNISTEncoder(snt.AbstractModule):
  def __init__(self,name='mnist_encoder'):
    super(MNISTEncoder,self).__init__(name=name)

  def _build(self,inputs,is_training):
    normalizedData = tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs, center=True,
                                               scale=True,
                                               training=is_training)

    conv_A11 = tf.layers.conv2d(normalizedData, 32, [5, 5], name='conv5x5_0',
                            kernel_regularizer=tf.nn.l2_loss)
    max_A12 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv_A11, [2, 2], 2, name='max_2x2_0')
conv_A13 = tf.layers.conv2d(max_A12, 64, [5, 5], name='conv_5x5_1',
                            kernel_regularizer=tf.nn.l2_loss)
    max_A14 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv_A13, [2, 2], 2, name='max_2x2_1')

    A1 = tf.layers.flatten(max_A14, 'A1')

    dense_A21 = tf.layers.dense(A1, 1024, name='dense_1024')
    drpt_A22 = tf.layers.dropout(dense_A21, 0.4, name='drpt_0.4',
                             training=is_training)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(drpt_A22, 10, name='logits')

    return logits
```

The module is called inside a tf.estimator model_fn as follows:

```
#[...]
with tf.variable_scope('DLModel'):
  mnistEncoder = MNISTEncoder('MainModule')
  logits = mnistEncoder(dataTensor,trainingFlag)
  output = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name='output')
```

This trains well. However, when I run tensorboard, nothing shows inside the *Graph* tab. I can still see the model's loss evolution and other scalar summaries inside the *Scalars* tab. If I don't use Sonnet and put the layers directly in the tf.estimator model_fn, it works perfectly and I can see my model's graph in tensorboard. (I'm using the latest versions of tensorflow, sonnet and tensorboard (versions 1.4,1.4 and 1.0 respectively).